# Chemmacros is not resetting the reactions counter in the new chapter

Tags: counters, chemmacros

I have a problem with `chemmacros` counter. When I type the reaction in different chapter, the counter of the equation doesn't restart. See the example

```
\documentclass[twoside]{ecsthesis}      
\graphicspath{{../Figures/}}  
\usepackage[sort &compress]{natbib}  
\usepackage[noprefix]{nomencl}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{array}

\setlength\epigraphwidth{8cm}
\setlength\epigraphrule{0pt}

\begin{document}
\chapter{1}

\begin{reaction}
A+C=B
 \end{reaction}

\chapter{2}

\begin{reaction}
A+C=B
 \end{reaction}

 \begin{reaction}
 A+C=B
  \end{reaction}

 \chapter{3}

 \begin{reaction}
 A+C=B
  \end{reaction}

 \begin{reaction}
 A+C=B
  \end{reaction}

\end{document}
```

I think that changing something in the .sty file could help but I do not have a clue about it.

Comment: Add `\numberwithin{reaction}{chapter}` to your preamble

Comment: It's working, thx!