# Beamer reactions numbering issue

Tags: beamer, chemmacros

Using the `reactions` environment in `Beamer` along with `\begin{itemize}[<+->]` causes the reactions to be renumbered when uncovering. In the following example the reactions are labelled 1-3 on the intial slide as required, but on uncovering the text in the list they are subsequently renumbered 4-5, 7-9, 10-12 and 13-15. Is there a quick fix to this without removing the `[<+->]` of `\begin{itemize}[<+->]` ;)

I tried putting `\numberwithin{reaction}{chapter}` `frame` and `slide` in place of `chapter` as suggested by this [Chemmacros is not resetting the reactions counter in the new chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134559/chemmacros-is-not-resetting-the-reactions-counter-in-the-new-chapter). I guess I need to replace `chapter` by the correct counter identifier...

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\begin{document}
\chemsetup[chemformula]{font-shape=sf}
\begin{frame}
\begin{reactions}
 Cl-Cl ->[$\Delta$][$h\nu$] 2 "\Lewis{0.,Cl}"  \label{react:init}\\
R3H + Cl "\Lewis{0.,\vphantom{H}}" -> R3 "\Lewis{0.,\vphantom{H}}" + HCl    \label{react:propagation}
\end{reactions}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item Initiation is cleavage of \ch{Cl-Cl} bond, Reaction~\ref{react:init}
\item 1st reaction is that of \ch{ Cl "\Lewis{0.,\vphantom{H}}"} with a hydrogen, Reaction~\ref{react:propagation1}
\item Once the carbon radical is formed \ch{ R3 "\Lewis{0.,\vphantom{H}}" }, subsequent bonding to the halogen \ch{Cl-Cl} can only occur at the radical site, Reaction~\ref{react:prop2}
\item Formation of \ch{HCl} is common to all reactants so determining factor must be the dissociation of the \ch{R-H} bond
\item Therefore not all \ch{C-H} bonds are equal
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
\resetcounteronoverlays{reaction}
```

to prevent the counter from stepping when using overlay specifications.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\resetcounteronoverlays{reaction}

\begin{document}
\chemsetup[chemformula]{font-shape=sf}
\begin{frame}
\begin{reactions}
 Cl-Cl ->[$\Delta$][$h\nu$] 2 "\Lewis{0.,Cl}"  \label{react:init}\\
R3H + Cl "\Lewis{0.,\vphantom{H}}" -> R3 "\Lewis{0.,\vphantom{H}}" + HCl    \label{react:propagation}
\end{reactions}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item Initiation is cleavage of \ch{Cl-Cl} bond, Reaction~\ref{react:init}
\item 1st reaction is that of \ch{ Cl "\Lewis{0.,\vphantom{H}}"} with a hydrogen, Reaction~\ref{react:propagation1}
\item Once the carbon radical is formed \ch{ R3 "\Lewis{0.,\vphantom{H}}" }, subsequent bonding to the halogen \ch{Cl-Cl} can only occur at the radical site, Reaction~\ref{react:prop2}
\item Formation of \ch{HCl} is common to all reactants so determining factor must be the dissociation of the \ch{R-H} bond
\item Therefore not all \ch{C-H} bonds are equal
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]