# reaction numbering with chapter numbers chemmacro

Tags: cleveref, chemmacros

I am trying to use the  reaction environment from chemmacro. How to get the numbers with chapter number like for equation numbers (e.g 1.1, 2.1 and so on)

```
\chapter{The First Chapter}
\begin{reaction}
    a + b = c
\end{reaction}

\begin{equation}
 a + b =2
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! As a new member, it is recommended to visit the [Welcome](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and the [Tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) pages to be informed about our format and also to know about [Minimal Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Comment: found the answer, one needs to add in preamble  \numberwithin{reaction}{chapter} https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134559/chemmacros-is-not-resetting-the-reactions-counter-in-the-new-chapter